# ToExpression with variable from InputField won't work

Tags: string-manipulation, inputfield

My code looks like this:

```
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], ToExpression[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[Head[x]]}]
```

When I intentionally input a list of numbers within the field, e.g. `1,2,3,4`,
`ToExpression` returns `$Failed` with the following error message:

> ToExpression::notstrbox: 1,2,3,4 is not a string or a box.
>   ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language
>   input.

and `Head` still outputs:

> String

I want the variable `x` to be further manipulated *numerically* with other functions, but if I don't optionally specify the `Head` of my input for `InputField`, `ContinuousAction` won't work; and if I specify the `Head` not as a `String`, but as a `Number`, then I'm unable to input the intended list of numbers, just a single number.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ImportString[]` instead:

```
DynamicModule[{x = ""}, 
              Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
                      Dynamic[ImportString[x, "List", "LineSeparators" -> ","]],
                      Dynamic[Head[x]]}]]
```

Comment: `Head` still outputs `String`.

Comment: @RichardSantiago obviously because you're not reassigning to `x`. You can't make `x` both a `String` for the `InputField` and a `Number`. You have to use two variables for two types.

Comment: @J.M. Ok, so `Dynamic[ImportString[x,"List"]]=y`, then `Dynamic[Head[y]]` should work instead?

Comment: A hint, @Richard: you can't have a `Dynamic[]` object on the left-hand side of an assignment. With that, as b3m2a1 notes, you need to maintain a second variable to store the converted list.

Comment: As an explicit example: `DynamicModule[{x = "", xc = {}}, Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic[xc = ImportString[x, "List"]], Dynamic[Head[xc]]}]]`.

Comment: I see, just now I did try `DynamicModule[{x = "", z}, z = ImportString[x, "List"]; 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[Head[z]]}]]`. Lol.

Comment: @J.M. What I need is to input a list of numbers in `InputField` and automatically generate their sum. I'm currently trying: `DynamicModule[{x}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[Activate@Plus[Delete[#, 0] &@ImportString[x, "List"]]]}]]` and `Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
  Dynamic[xNum = ImportString[x, "List"]], 
  Dynamic[Activate@Plus@Delete[xNum, 0]]}]` with no luck.

Comment: Maybe ask that as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

`Dynamic` isn't transparent to evaluation. You'll need to bring the `ToExpression` inside:

```
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
  Dynamic[ToExpression[x]], Dynamic[Head[x]]}]
```

If you want to manipulate `x` later then you'll want:

```
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True], 
  Dynamic[xNum = ToExpression[x]], Dynamic[Head[xNum]]}]
```

Where you can then play with `xNum` normally.

Note that J.M.'s suggestion to use `ImportString[x, "List"]` is probably a good one for you here.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. `Head` still outputs  `String`.

Comment: It doesn't work how? Because `ToExpression` doesn't work or because there's a bad variable binding?

Comment: I wish I could paste the picture here. I basically copy-pasted your code. I did the same with the first answer I got. For example, an input of `1,3,4` outputs `$Failed` and `String` underneath.

Comment: That's because `ToExpression["1, 3, 4"]` fails... It's obviously not a valid expression. Try `ImportString[x, "List"]` instead or supply a valid expression like `"{1, 3, 4}"`.